# Storing cvMat Objects in an Array - OpenCV - iPhone

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, opencv

I am working on an OpenCV app where I create a number of cvMat objects as follows :

```
UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.jpg"];
cv::Mat tempMat = [testImage CVMat];
cv::cvtColor(tempMat, grayImg, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

What I then want to do is store the result (here called grayImg) in a NSMutableArray.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whatever object you need to store in NSArray, you may do it like below:

```
cv::Mat tempMat = [testImage CVMat];
cv::Mat *pointer = (cv::Mat *)tempMat;
id object = [NSValue valueWithPointer:pointer];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: object, nil];
```

Comment: Line number 2 fails on latest XCode.

Comment: Wait... You just cast a `cv::Mat` to a `cv::Mat*`? Are you sure that works?

Comment: `Cannot cast from type 'cv::Mat' to pointer type 'cv::Mat *'`